# Using result of `JSON.decode` in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, get

So I have an action in my controller that does a `get_response` to an API:

```
  def memeapi
    require "net/http"
    require "uri"

    @meme = Meme.new(params[:meme])

    url = "http://version1.api.memegenerator.net/Instance_Create?username=apigen&password=SECRET&languageCode=en&generatorID=#{@meme.memeid}&imageID=#{@meme.imgid}&text0=#{@meme.text0}&text1=#{@meme.text1}"
    resp = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url))
    data = resp.body
    # I want to convert it to the Rails data structure - a hash
    result = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(data)


  end
```

Ok but now I want to get back the information, use it to create another object, but I cant even format the information I am getting, can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong, what am I missing?

I want to be able to access the information from the `get_response`... 
Thank you.

This is the JSON structure

```
{"success":true,"result":{"generatorID":45,"displayName":"Insanity Wolf","urlName":"Insanity-Wolf","totalVotesScore":0,"imageUrl":"/cache/images/400x/0/0/20.jpg","instanceID":13226270,"text0":"push","text1":null,"instanceImageUrl":"/cache/instances/400x/12/12916/13226270.jpg","instanceUrl":"http://memegenerator.net/instance/13226270"}}
```

I dont want to save all the fields btw...

Comment: what does the JSON look like? Also, what's the problem with the "thing" that's probably saved in `result` after the decoding?

Comment: I edited the question with the json structure, the problem is that I cant even see the content, I am pretty sure the problem is that I dont know how to handle the data... T

Comment: what do you want to do with the data?

Comment: At least see it... Hehe I want to save specific fields from the json in my db.

Comment: Okay, in that case my answer might actually help you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`result` will look something like this after `JSON.decode` in your code.

```
{ 
  'success' => true,
  'result'  => {
    "generatorID"      => 45,
    "displayName"      => "Insanity Wolf",
    "urlName"          => "Insanity-Wolf",
    "totalVotesScore"  => 0,
    "imageUrl"         => "/cache/images/400x/0/0/20.jpg",
    "instanceID"       => 13226270,
    "text0"            => "push",
    "text1"            => nil,
    "instanceImageUrl" => "/cache/instances/400x/12/12916/13226270.jpg",
    "instanceUrl"      => "http://memegenerator.net/instance/13226270"
  }
}
```

You have a nested hash (hash as part of a hash) here, which you can access like this:

```
image_url = result['result']['imageUrl']   # => "/cache/images/400x/0/0/20.jpg"
```

What you actually want to do with this information, I cannot guess. Maybe you want to update the `Meme` object you created?

```
@meme.url = image_url
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was not getting thank you very much. Jeje you rock man.

Comment: Man sorry for the abuse but you know any way I can format a variable to remove the spaces and replace it with "%20" so it could be URL friendly?

Comment: @Mau: No problem. You can use `URI.escape(string)`. You might need to `require 'uri'` first.

Comment: Again, thank you very much, and if you need anything from Javascript or PHP hehe let me know with a message. (I am very new to ruby)